# Any workflow recommendation for 2.5-D pixel art style?

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor, pixel-art

I am working on a little project that requires me to create a lot of low-resolution artwork on various sort-of basic geometry. For example a house would be just a cube with a triangle on top for the roof. Now I want to paint my pixelated texture tiles onto the surface of this object.

What I am doing right now is unwrapping the UV coordinates of the given object onto a map of sufficient size and then use the stencil texture painter to project my 2D artwork onto the surface of the object. This however is very tedious and although Blender 2.8 is a giant leap towards a more user friendly interface I am not satisfied with the workflow I'm currently following.

For instance, I would like to project the stencil already aligned with the given face normal instead of using the screen space for that. Is this possible? I could not find any option or documentation on this. This is also especially annoying when the mapped texture isn't aligned to the XYZ grid at all.

I'm also having trouble with the preview image of the stencil (the transparent one that is projected to the viewport). Because I am doing 8-bit texture mapping I really much don't want any kind of texture interpolation as it destroys the effect intended. I found out how to actually paint nearest-neighbour interpolated textures, but the preview itself is very much blurred. I am avoiding this in a way by using up-scaled images, but that complicates the drawing process even further.

Last but not least I am struggling with tile alignment. I did not yet find a way to easily align stencil tiles next to each other without any kind of distortion or gaps. Is there some kind of grid or snapping tool I can use while painting? I couldn't find any.

Perhaps I'm doing it completely wrong. In this case I would love to read some suggestions on how I could achieve this kind of task in a more straight forward way. I'm also very much open to try plugins, both free and commercial, or anything that might help increase productivity.

Thank you for any advice!

EDIT:

As requested I've attached a couple of images to demonstrate the problem.

First off, this is how i am painting the textures (obviously from screen-space):

[image]

Well, this is not actually what I am doing but it demonstrates the issue as I really like the texture not to project from screen space but rather aligned with the normals of the surface which would allow me to draw "across the edge" without any gap or distortion.

The next one shows the issue with the stencil itself:

[image]

As you can see its really hard to draw pixel perfect as the stencil is interpolated smoothly. I like this to be nearest-neighbour if possible.

EVEN MORE EDIT:

There seems to be a similar mode in sculpture painting called "Area Plane". From my understanding this is allowing sculpturing on the mesh surface instead from view projection. If that would be true this is exactly what I am looking for in terms of texture painting. Why is this option not available there?

Comment: Can you show some screenshots of what you mean so that we can respond correctly? First thing in my head is that if you want pixelated texture, you should really use small images that will naturally appear that way.

Comment: Thank you Craig for commenting my question. I've attached two screenshots to hopefully describe the situation.

As for small images: Yes, I agree. The reason I am not doing this is because of the blurred stencil effect demonstrated on the second image. I did not find a way to get around this. (By the way the stencil source image on the screenshot actually is an unscaled 1:1 version)

Comment: Probably not available -yet- because the paint system was designed around the Image Editor first, and not for the 3d view until a GSOC project over a couple of years brought us the 3d viewport texture painting. I have to ask why you can't just select the faces you intend to paint and then use the stencil in the UV Image Editor on the corresponding face? Or just map the image to UV and use it as a texture?

Comment: Sorry, but still not sure to understand what you want to do... well was about to write nearly the same as @CraigDJones just commented.

Comment: No need for being sorry, I guess I'm just not great at explaining this stuff. Anyway, allow me to try another explanation of what I'm struggling with

Imagine the tileset in the screenshots would be parts of a building instead. In the good old days i would pick a wall and place it many times on a grid next to each other, maybe a window here, a door there... I'm sure you know what I mean. Now in Blender i don't seem to have any grid or axis to lock my tiles to, so i have to be very careful not to create gaps. Also I don't want any distortion in perspective, just a plain mapping on the surface

Comment: @CraigDJones I may be able to use the UV editor directly, but as far as I can see this may be way more complicated than just painting on the surface itself. This is why i was hoping to use the Texture Painter. Maybe is this something I'm misconceiving here?

Comment: Painting them on as they are there is too complicated - UV mapping an image to a plane is easier imho. Is that a sprite sheet? Have you looked into the UV modifiers?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out! Yes, that is a sprite sheet indeed. It's not the exact one I'm using, I just picked this one from Google to give you a better idea of what I'm after. 
I have some experience with manual UV mapping, yes. That was how I used to do it in 3D Max back in the days. Would you recommend that I do my texturing on the UV mapped image inside PhotoShop (or image editor of choice) then? If so, how would I be able to achieve a planar mapping? I mean, I could do this by hand I guess if this is the preferred approach, but I'd like to keep things simple really.